# how to choose image on button click event without using file upload control in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to show an image in an image box on a button_click event, without using file upload control in asp.net with c#

```
protected void btnBrowseImage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btnBrowseImage.Text = "Click";

    if (btnBrowseImage.Text == "Click")
    {
        //I want to show here image box fill with image
    }               
}
```

Comment: Where is that image stored?
From where you want to choose image?

Comment: Image is stored into my Image folder and I want to open that folder on button click.

Answer (score 0):

`ImageControl.Source = @"Path to your image";` ?

Comment: Are you asking a question or answering the question? If you are answering, add some explanation as to how this solves the issue